# Lambda giving me a "KeyError"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to implement a Lambda script that will check for encryption on newly created s3 buckets. If buckets are found that are not encrypted, I want Lambda to force SSE-KMS on those buckets. I am using the following code:

```
from boto3 import resource, client
from logging import getLogger, info, error, debug
from os import environ
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

SSEAlgorithm = "aws:kms"
KMSMasterKeyID = environ['KMSMasterKeyID'] 

class Enforce_EBS_Encryption(object):

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.s3_client = client('s3')
        
        self.logger = getLogger()
        self.logger.setLevel("INFO")
        self.unencryptedbucket = list()

    def getlistofUnEncryptedBucket(self):
        response = self.s3_client.list_buckets()
        for bucket in response['Buckets']:
            try:
                resp_encryption = self.s3_client.get_bucket_encryption(
                    Bucket=bucket['Name']
                )
                rules = resp_encryption['ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration']['Rules']
                info("{0} is already encrypted : Encryption : {1}".format(bucket['Name'],rules))
            except ClientError as e:
                if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError':
                    info("{0} is not encrypted but will be, No Encrytion found".format(bucket['Name']))
                    self.unencryptedbucket.append(bucket['Name'])
                else:
                    error("Unexpected error on Bucket: {0}".format(bucket['Name']))
    
    def _putEncryptiononSingleBucket(self,bucket_name):
        resp = self.s3_client.put_bucket_encryption(
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration={
                'Rules': [
                    {
                        'ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault': {
                            'SSEAlgorithm': SSEAlgorithm,
                            'KMSMasterKeyID': KMSMasterKeyID
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        )
    
    def forceEncrytionOnUnEncryptedBucket(self):
        for bucket in self.unencryptedbucket:
            self._putEncryptiononSingleBucket(bucket)
            info("The Bucket : {0} has been encrypted with KMS key".format(bucket))
            

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("***** Start Processing ****")
    s3_encryption = Enforce_EBS_Encryption()
    s3_encryption.getlistofUnEncryptedBucket()
    s3_encryption.forceEncrytionOnUnEncryptedBucket()
    print("***** End Processing ****")
```

However, when testing, I receive the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'KMSMasterKeyID'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 696, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 7, in <module>\n    KMSMasterKeyID = environ['KMSMasterKeyID']\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 681, in __getitem__\n    raise KeyError(key) from None\n"
  ]
}

Request ID:
"1a3ceb27-f2ed-4cf9-8b89-87e593a75ac6"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 1a3ceb27-f2ed-4cf9-8b89-87e593a75ac6 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'KMSMasterKeyID'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 7, in <module>
    KMSMasterKeyID = environ['KMSMasterKeyID']
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
END RequestId: 1a3ceb27-f2ed-4cf9-8b89-87e593a75ac6
REPORT RequestId: 1a3ceb27-f2ed-4cf9-8b89-87e593a75ac6  Duration: 4130.89 ms    Billed Duration: 4200 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 25 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That variable was not found in the environment.  Did you set it?

Comment: It looks like your environment doesn't have a `KMSMasterKeyID` variable. What you  are doing in the rest of the code doesn't really matter because it doesn't run.

Comment: Where do I set that variable? I see multiple keys in my KMS, just not sure what the master key is referring to. Thank you

Comment: Only you know what `KMSMasterKeyID` should be. Did you write the function yourself? If not referer to whomever wrote it as ask what `KMSMasterKeyID` is.